# Simple store validation Request don't return error just redirect to form view with 302 error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I don't understand why Laravel don't send me validation error and redirects me to the view with 302 error.

I just have simple forms in the view which just send this :

```
            @else
                        {{Form::open(array('route'=>'Link.store','name'=>'storeLink'.$key))}}
                        <div class="md-form input-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="route_name" value="{{$route['name']}}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="href" value="{{$route['uri']}}">
                            <input pattern="[a-zA-Zéè \-]{3,35}" required class="form-control" type="text" name="title"
                                   id="linkTitle{{$key}}"
                                   value=""
                                   placeholder="Ajoutez ici un titre à ce lien pour le rendre disponibles pour les menus">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                             <button type="button"
                                     class="btn btn-default ml-2 btnUpdateLink">Ajouter</button>
                        </span>

                            {{Form::close()}}
                        </div>
                    @endif
```

the forms sends data to my store method :

```
            public function store(LinkRequest $request)
                {

                    //dd($request->all());

                    try{

                        Link::create($request->all());
                        return redirect(route('Permission.index'))->with('success-message','Lien crée');

                    }catch (Exception $e){
                        $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
                        dd($errorCode);
                        if($errorCode == 1062){
                            return redirect(route('Link.index'))
                                ->with('error_message','Un lien existe déjà avec ce titre')
                                ->with('create_name',$request->get('title'));
                        }
                    }

                }
```

and here is my LinkRequest class :

```
                public function rules()
                {
                    return [
                        'title'=> array(
                            'required',
                            'max:35',
                            'unique:links,title,'.$this->Link,
                            'regex:[a-zA-Zéè]',
                        ),
                        'route_name'=>array(
                            'required'
                        ),
                        'href'=>array(
                            'required'
                        ),

                    ];
                }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: But 302 is not an error. It is just a redirection. And you are making redirections in your code... So...

Comment: Yes ok, but when I make a simple dd($request-all()) in the controller I got the same result, that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Shouldn't you put a backslash "\" before the Exception (\Exception) ?

Comment: same result....

Comment: If I change the LinkRequest parameter to a simple Request the dd($request->all()) works but if I change it for LinkRequest  I just have a redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior with FormRequests I believe :

*From https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests*

> If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display.

Your errors should be accessible in your Blade templates with the variable $errors!

Example from [the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) :

```
@if($errors->any())
    <ul>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
      <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: Try using the $errors variable as I stated above! Its in that specific variable that the errors are set. Just copy/paste the snippet as a quick check and put it in the view which contains your form

Comment: I made a mistake, the right function to use is any(), not has(), sorry about that

Comment: yes now I have an error "incorrect format" it seems that my pattern fails

Comment: Yes it's the regex pattern in the validation request

Comment: Indeed your regular expression is not valid, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: just a simple alpha string with spaces accepted and I don't understand why 'regex:[a-zA-Zéè ]' fails when my input is "Login page"

Comment: 'regex:/^[A-Za-zéèà"' ]+$/u' is something basic you could try!

Comment: Thanks yes i made a mistake the [ shouldn't be in the regex Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you're adding the CSRF field into your form. This is accomplished by doing `{{ csrf_field() }}` inside of the form.

Also, you seemed to have some incorrect formatting within your form. the `md-form` div opening was within the form while the closing was outside of the form.

```
@else
    {{Form::open(array('route'=>'Link.store','name'=>'storeLink'.$key))}}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="md-form input-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="route_name" value="{{$route['name']}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="href" value="{{$route['uri']}}">
            <input pattern="[a-zA-Zéè \-]{3,35}" required class="form-control" type="text" name="title"
                   id="linkTitle{{$key}}"
                   value=""
                   placeholder="Ajoutez ici un titre à ce lien pour le rendre disponibles pour les menus">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ml-2 btnUpdateLink">Ajouter</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    {{Form::close()}}
@endif
```

Comment: you don't need to insert the csrf manually, and I see the token in the parameters in devtools

Answer (score 0):

I made this but no errors are shown (it works in my other views) :

```
@if(Session::has('error_message'))
                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="flash_message"><em><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle mr-2"></i>
                        {{ session('error_message') }}</em></div>
            @endif
```